# get_attribute problem with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, attributes

I've been suing Selenium-Python for about 2 months. I want to get 'rel' attribute value. Every other values are working, but 'rel' value returns none
i.e

```
<span class="isOdd" data-ratio="-1" data-outcome="1.85" data-percentage="23" data-market-id="1677954" data-outcomeno="1" data-id="undefined" rel="[{'fixedoddsweb':'1.62','ratiostatus':0},{'fixedoddsweb':'1.90','ratiostatus':-1},{'fixedoddsweb':'1.85','ratiostatus':-1}]" style="" xpath="1">1.85
```

and if I try like;

```
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='eventContentContainer']/div[2]/div[1]/span[4]/ul/li[1]/span")
print(str(link.get_attribute("class")))
```

it returns, **isOdd** and its correct .
Or if I try to take data-id it returns **undefined** which is correct value again. Now,

**If I try to take rel attribute it returns "None"**

I searched on the internet, they always same thing again and again about get_attribute value. I am not good in HTML. Is there any special thing for **rel** attribute?

Edit 1:
I also used **execute.script()** for another element, and the output like;

```
{'class': 'isOdd', 'data-id': 'undefined', 'data-market-id': '1679546', 'data-outcome': '3.10', 'data-outcomeno': '1', 'data-percentage': '3', 'data-ratio': '-1'}
```

every attribute was printed except 'rel'

Edit 2:
I found the REAL problem, if you wait on the element about 1-2 seconds, then some tags pops on the elenment then it has **rel** attribute. Do you know how to wait on the element about 1 sec then click? I guess it is about dynamic element

Comment: Can't replicate the issue (tried artificially setting 'rel' to that value and can retrieve it just fine). Can you share the webpage url? Btw, you don't need the `str` conversion the `print` statement.

Comment: You might not looking at the `span` you think you are looking? `.get_attribute("rel"))` works just fine on that website.

Comment: Can you plz take this XPath 
//*[@id="eventContentContainer"]/div[4]/div[4]/span[4]/ul/li[1]/span
and try to reach rel attribute

Comment: Yes, that relates to this full xpath /html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div[4]/span[4]/ul/li[1]/span, which does not have a rel attribute.

Comment: I see the problem, if you wait on the element after 1 seconds. Some tags pops on the elenment then it has rel attribute. Do you know how to wait on the element about 1 sec then click?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are after?

```
link=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='eventContentContainer']/div[4]/div[4]/span[4]/ul/li[4]/span")))
print(link.get_attribute('rel'))
```

Add these imports before trying the above:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: No I know this, I Edites 2nd time my question. Can you look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, but also it doesn't work. It is all about hover I guess. If I locate the mouse on the element, then it has 'rel' attribute. Firstly there is no 'rel' attribute. If I open page > hover my mouse on element > then use .get_attribute() . I found my problem. But idk how to hover my mouse to the element

Comment: I don't use python, but like you said the important thing is to determine when the attribute gets populated. On what action and timing. From what you say, it appears that the attribute populates on a hover. In Selenium with Java, what we would do is to use an Actions class to move to the Element. That would be the equivalent to hovering. Would not be able to comment further without having a look at the site.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. There is 'rel' attribute at first. If you hover on element, then it has 'rel' attribute.
Thank to @0buz for the patience. But I found the solution.

```
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='eventContentContainer']/div[2]/div[1]/span[4]/ul/li[1]/span")
hov = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(link)
hov.perform()
time.sleep(3)

print(link.get_attribute("rel"))
```

That's all my basic mistake shortly :)